# Ampere's Law and Wires?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, magnetostatics

For a current carrying wire, the magnetic field $B$ is given by:

$$B = \frac{u_oI}{2\pi r}$$

Is this only valid for a cylindrical wire?

Comment: It is valid for an infinite cilindrical wire.

Comment: @jinawee Oops, I mean't cylindrical, not symmetrical haha. Does this not apply for non-cylindrical wires?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just see the proof in any book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampere's law says:
$$\oint_C\vec B\cdot d\vec\ell=\mu_0I_{\rm{enc}}$$
To get the result you mention we apply cylindrical symmetry to the problem and see that $\vec B\parallel\vec\ell$. Then we get the simple case where the LHS becomes
$$B\int_0^{2\pi}rd\theta=2\pi Br$$
which gives the expression you mentioned above.

If the symmetry condition is relaxed, then all of a sudden $\vec B=\vec B(\theta)$ and it is no longer easy to solve for the magnetic field.